Should I provide my own Instagram App Review Test Credentials?
I have been asked by the facebook/instagram app reviewers to provide test credentials which includes a facebook account and an instagram account for testing of my app in the process. Is this normal? What is the best approach to doing this? Note: Im using Facebook Login For Business and the App is going to be A Tech Provider
I set up test accounts for facebook and instagram.
